# Where is this weird island?

Tags: riddle

Do you know me or do you know where exactly I am?

> I am an island in the atlantic ocean.
>
> Every day, people appear and disappear on me.
>
> I am invisible to humans but machines can recognize me.

Hint 1:

> The coordinates are important

Hint 2(big hint):

> It has to to something with the defininition of non-existent

This puzzle is only partially by me/inspired by something. You can look it up if you take a look at the [accepted answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/95398/65170)(by @[dantechguy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/66450/dantechguy)) as he discovered my inspiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Null island, I remembered it from this video! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjvIpI-1w84

Explanation: "Atlantic"

> Null Island is the place on the globe with a latitude and longitude of (0°, 0°). These coordinates map to a position in the Atlantic ocean.

"Disappear", "Machines"

> When it comes to computer processing, there is an important distinction between `0` and `NULL`. `0` means that a data item has a value of **zero**, but `NULL` means that there is **no data** there, e.g. it doesn't have a value, not even a value of zero. When computer applications have to process coordinates, your device can say "my position is `(90, 135)`", and you would be at the north pole. Or it can say "my position is `(NULL, NULL)`, and it would not know where you are (there is no data). Sometimes applications can accidentally interpret `NULL` as `0`, and so therefore every time your device says that it doesn't know your location (`(NULL, NULL)`), the app reads it as "oh, they're at position `(0, 0)` instead. Usually these mistakes are corrected quickly, so as soon as the application receives the *actual* coordinates from the device, it updates them, essentially "teleporting" the person.

Wikipedia

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island

Comment: Wow, you discovered my inspiration.

Comment: Ooh nice, I learned something. But please [edit] your answer to include some explanation, just in case that Youtube link goes dead in the future (as Youtube links often do).

Answer (score 1):

I think answer is :

> network or internet or webservice (wsdl)

I am an island in the atlantic ocean. :

> You are webservice which are on network or  internet

I am invisible to humans but machines recognize me. :

> Human's can't see webservices but, it is present and machines recognize it.

Every day, people appear and disappear on me.

> people send request to webservice ( appear to it)

Comment: This is not what I've thought of but it seems not bad.

Comment: @dan1st so this is not right ?

Comment: It may be an alternative solution. I am considering upvoting it if you can think of more information about the island in the atlantic ocean :)

Comment: After searching alot i found `Porto Santos` means holy port  .but,  I don’t know if its right or not  :)

Comment: No, it is something really weird - but I still like your solution